# How to close the current element on click

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

This is very silly question. But i am new to html, jquery. Can anyone give me the solution on this.

How to close the element on click

```
<a>test</a>
```

When i click test it show close/hide()

I tried as `this.hide() onClick` but it didnt work anymore.`(<a onclick='this.hide()'>test</a>)`

Comment: [How jQuery Works](http://learn.jquery.com/about-jquery/how-jquery-works/).

Answer (score 7):

In the click handler `this` will be the native DOM element which does not have the `hide()` method - you need to turn it into a jQuery object. Try this:

```
<a href="#" class="foo">test</a>
```

```js
$('.foo').click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $(this).hide();
});
```

Couple of notes; firstly using `onclick` attributes is outdated. If you use jQuery, use it to hook up your events.

Secondly, `a` elements must have a `href` or `name` attribute, and as such you'll need to use `event.preventDefault()` to stop the default behaviour when it's clicked on.

Answer (score 3):

`.hide()` is a method provided by jQuery, it is not available in the dom element.

```
<a onclick='$(this).hide()'>test</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try like this using jquery:

```
<a class"some_link">test</a>

$(function(){
    $(".some_link").click(function(){
        $(this).hide(); // $(this).remove(); to remove
    });
});
```